# Aggregate not working in prefetched queryset in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-aggregation

I have a query that I am trying to aggregate values so I can calculate balances more quickly than querying multiple times to get the values needed.

Overall I simply want to be able to run, but the aggregation that seems to be what would allow that isn't working:

```
header_accounts = custom_report.account_tree_header.all()

for header_account in header_accounts:
    for regular_account in header_account.associated_regular_account_tree_accounts.all():
        gl_account = regular_account.associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts
        gl_entries = gl_account.range_gl # range entries
        # this does not work below...
        prior_credit =  gl_account.old_gl.prior_credit_amount
        prior_debit =  gl_account.old_gl.prior_debit_amount
```

When I run the query below with aggregate instead of annotate, I get an `AttributeError` `'dict' object has no attribute '_add_hints'`

**How can I do this?**

```
custom_report = AccountTree.objects.select_related().prefetch_related(
    'account_tree_total', 'account_tree_regular',
    Prefetch('account_tree_header', queryset=AccountTreeHeader.objects.select_related(
        'associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts', 'associated_total_account_tree_account__associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts'
    ).prefetch_related(
        'associated_regular_account_tree_accounts',
        Prefetch('associated_regular_account_tree_accounts__associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts__general_ledger',
                 queryset=GeneralLedger.objects.select_related(
                 ).filter(Q(
                     accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in=property_pks,
                     journal_line_item__property__pk__in=property_pks,
                     _connector=Q.OR,
                 ), date_entered__date__gte=start_date, date_entered__date__lte=end_date).order_by('date_entered'), to_attr='range_gl'),
        # ISSUE IS HERE....
        Prefetch('associated_regular_account_tree_accounts__associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts__general_ledger',
                 queryset=GeneralLedger.objects.select_related(
                 ).filter(Q(
                     accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in=property_pks,
                     journal_line_item__property__pk__in=property_pks,
                     _connector=Q.OR,
                 ), date_entered__date__lte=start_date).aggregate(prior_credit_amount=Sum('credit_amount'), prior_debit_amount=Sum('debit_amount')), to_attr='old_gl'),
    )),
).get(pk=custom_report.pk)
```

As a note in the traceback the error occurs in `.get(pk=custom_report.pk)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This overall was a Subquery issue where I needed to Annotate an Aggregate to figure out the solution. The issue became that I had to pass the filters to the Prefetched aggregation, and for whatever reason that was not directly or easily possible in Django.

For example as an easy thing to reproduce:

```
# does not work...the general_ledger date filters are not there, not sure why?
# calculates from all time...
GLAccount.objects.filter(account_identifier='1011.00').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('general_ledger', queryset=GeneralLedger.objects.filter(
        date_entered__date__lte=start_date).distinct()),
).aggregate(
    Sum('general_ledger__credit_amount'), Sum('general_ledger__debit_amount')
)
#{'general_ledger__credit_amount__sum': Decimal('525.00'), 'general_ledger__debit_amount__sum': Decimal('707782.18')}

# works fine...and filters as expected with date range intact
GeneralLedger.objects.filter(
    date_entered__date__lte=start_date,
    account__account_identifier='1011.00').aggregate(
    Sum('credit_amount'), Sum('debit_amount')
)
# {'credit_amount__sum': Decimal('525.00'), 'debit_amount__sum': Decimal('629231.18')}
```

I ended up finding a package `django-sql-utils`: https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils/tree/master/sql_util

And it assists in the subquery pretty easily as shown below:

```
custom_report = AccountTree.objects.select_related().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('account_tree_header', queryset=AccountTreeHeader.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('associated_regular_account_tree_accounts__associated_account_from_chart_of_accounts',
                 queryset=GLAccount.objects.prefetch_related(
                     Prefetch('general_ledger', queryset=GeneralLedger.objects.filter(
                         property__pk__in=property_pks,
                         date_entered__date__gte=start_date,
                         date_entered__date__lte=end_date).order_by('date_entered'), to_attr='range_gl'),
                 )
                 .annotate(
                     prior_credit=SubqueryAggregate(
                         'general_ledger__credit_amount',
                         filter=(Q(date_entered__date__lte=start_date) & Q(property__pk__in=property_pks)),
                         aggregate=Sum),
                     prior_debit=SubqueryAggregate(
                         'general_ledger__debit_amount',
                         filter=(Q(date_entered__date__lte=start_date) & Q(property__pk__in=property_pks)),
                         aggregate=Sum)
                 )),
    )),
).get(pk=custom_report.pk)
```

And that annotated aggregation of a prefetched item is possible using this code from the package:

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError
from django.db.models import Q, F, QuerySet, BooleanField, Sum, Avg, ForeignKey
from django.db.models import Subquery as DjangoSubquery, OuterRef, IntegerField, Min, Max, Count
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP

class Subquery(DjangoSubquery):
    def __init__(self, queryset_or_expression, **extra):
        if isinstance(queryset_or_expression, QuerySet):
            self.queryset = queryset_or_expression
            self.query = self.queryset.query
            super(Subquery, self).__init__(queryset_or_expression, **extra)
        else:
            expression = queryset_or_expression
            if not hasattr(expression, 'resolve_expression'):
                expression = F(expression)
            self.expression = expression
            self.query = None
            self.queryset = None
            self.output_field = extra.get('output_field')
            self.extra = extra
            self.filter = extra.pop('filter', Q())
            self.distinct = extra.pop('distinct', None)
            self.outer_ref = extra.pop('outer_ref', None)
            self.unordered = extra.pop('unordered', self.unordered)

    def resolve_expression(self, query=None, allow_joins=True, reuse=None, summarize=False, for_save=False):
        # The parent class, Subquery, takes queryset as an initialization parameter
        # so self.queryset needs to be set before we call `resolve_expression`.
        # We can set it here because we now have access to the outer query object,
        # which is the first parameter of this method.
        if self.query is None or self.queryset is None:
            # Don't pass allow_joins = False here
            queryset = self.get_queryset(query.clone(), True, reuse, summarize)
            self.queryset = queryset
            self.query = queryset.query
        return super(Subquery, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)

    def get_queryset(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize):
        # This is a customization hook for child classes to override the base queryset computed automatically
        return self._get_base_queryset(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)

    def _get_base_queryset(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize):
        resolved_expression = self.expression.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
        model = self._get_model_from_resolved_expression(resolved_expression)

        reverse, outer_ref = self._get_reverse_outer_ref_from_expression(model, query)

        outer_ref = self.outer_ref or outer_ref
        q = self.filter & Q(**{reverse: OuterRef(outer_ref)})
        queryset = model._default_manager.filter(q)
        if self.unordered:
            queryset = queryset.order_by()
        return queryset.values(reverse)

    def _get_model_from_resolved_expression(self, resolved_expression):
        """
        Retrieve the correct model from the resolved_expression.

        For simple expressions like F('child__field_name'), both of these are equivalent and correct:
        resolved_expression.field.model
        resolved_expression.target.model

        For many to many relations, resolved_expression.field.model goes one table deeper than
        necessary. We get more efficient SQL only going as far as we need. In this case only
        resolved_expression.target.model is correct.

        For functions of multiple columns like Coalesce, there is no resolved_expression.target,
        we have to recursively go through the source_expressions until we get to the bottom and
        get the target from there.
        """
        def get_target(res_expr):
            for expression in res_expr.get_source_expressions():
                return get_target(expression)
            return res_expr.field if res_expr.target.null else res_expr.target
        return get_target(resolved_expression).model

    def _get_fields_model_from_path(self, path, model, target_model):
        fields = []

        # We want the paths reversed because we have the forward join info
        # and we need the string that tells us how to go back
        paths = list(reversed(path))
        for p in paths:
            if p.to_opts.model == model and ((p.from_opts.model != target_model or p.m2m) or not fields):
                if getattr(p.join_field, 'related_query_name', None) and isinstance(p.join_field, ForeignKey):
                    try:
                        fields.append(p.join_field.related_query_name())
                    except TypeError:  # Sometimes related_query_name is a string instead of a callable that returns a string
                        fields.append(p.join_field.related_query_name)
                elif hasattr(p.join_field, 'field'):
                    fields.append(p.join_field.field.name)
                model = p.from_opts.model

        return fields, model

    def _get_reverse_outer_ref_from_expression(self, model, query):
        source = self.expression
        while hasattr(source, 'get_source_expressions'):
            source = source.get_source_expressions()[0]
        field_list = source.name.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
        path, _, _, _ = query.names_to_path(field_list, query.get_meta(), allow_many=True, fail_on_missing=True)

        fields, model = self._get_fields_model_from_path(path, model, query.model)
        reverse = LOOKUP_SEP.join(fields)

        join_field = path[0].join_field
        if model == query.model or len(path) == 1:
            try:
                outer_ref = join_field.get_related_field().name
            except AttributeError:
                outer_ref = 'pk'
        else:
            outer_ref = join_field.name

        return reverse, outer_ref


class SubqueryAggregate(Subquery):
    """
    The intention of this class is to provide an API similar to other aggregate
    classes like Count, Min, Max, Sum, etc but generate SQL that performs the
    calculation in a subquery instead of adding joins to the outer query. This
    is commonly a performance improvement. It also reduces the risk of
    forgetting to add `distinct` when the joins duplicate data.

    E.g.,
    queryset.annotate(min_field=Min('field'))

    is replaced by

    queryset.annotate(min_field=SubqueryAggregate('field', aggregate=Min))

    A child class of SubqueryAggregate with `aggregate=Min` allows:

    queryset.annotate(min_field=SubqueryMin('field'))

    """
    aggregate = None  # Must be set by the subclass, or passed as kwarg
    unordered = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **extra):
        self.aggregate = extra.pop('aggregate', self.aggregate)
        self.ordering = extra.pop('ordering', None)
        assert self.aggregate is not None, "Error: Attempt to instantiate a " \
                                           "SubqueryAggregate with no aggregate function"
        super(SubqueryAggregate, self).__init__(*args, **extra)

    def get_queryset(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize):
        queryset = self._get_base_queryset(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
        annotation = self._get_annotation(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
        return queryset.annotate(**annotation).values('aggregation')

    def aggregate_kwargs(self):
        aggregate_kwargs = dict()
        if self.distinct:
            aggregate_kwargs['distinct'] = self.distinct
        if self.ordering:
            aggregate_kwargs['ordering'] = self.ordering

        return aggregate_kwargs

    def _get_annotation(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize):
        resolved_expression = self.expression.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
        model = self._get_model_from_resolved_expression(resolved_expression)
        queryset = model._default_manager.all()
        # resolved_expression was resolved in the outer query to get the model
        # target_expression is resolved in the subquery to get the field to aggregate
        target_expression = self._resolve_to_target(resolved_expression, queryset.query, allow_joins, reuse,
                                                    summarize)

        # Add test for output_field, distinct, and when resolved_expression.field.name isn't what we're aggregating

        if not self.output_field:
            self._output_field = self.output_field = target_expression.field

        kwargs = self.aggregate_kwargs()

        aggregation = self.aggregate(target_expression, **kwargs)

        annotation = {
            'aggregation': aggregation
        }

        return annotation

    def _resolve_to_target(self, resolved_expression, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize):
        if resolved_expression.get_source_expressions():
            c = resolved_expression.copy()
            c.is_summary = summarize
            new_source_expressions = [self._resolve_to_target(source_expressions, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
                                      for source_expressions in resolved_expression.get_source_expressions()]
            c.set_source_expressions(new_source_expressions)
            return c

        else:
            try:
                return F(resolved_expression.target.name).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
            except (FieldError, AttributeError):
                return resolved_expression
```