# Django query to sum first value in a nested fforeign key

Tags: django, django-models

Given the three below models

```
    class GrandFather(models.Model):
        pass

    class Father(models.Model):
        grandfather = models.ForeignKey(GrandFather)

    class Son(models.Model):
        father = models.ForeignKey(Father)
        date = models.DateField()
        value = models.IntegerField()
```

What would the annotate command be to get the sum of the value of the latest son for each father, for all fathers in a grandfather.

I can do a subquery, but don't know how to do a nested subquery. Don't know how to even go at that!

Comment: This is one of my answers showing a nested subquery with `django-sql-utils`  from: https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils/tree/master/sql_util
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287750/8382028 maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 sons = Son.objects.filter(father__grandfather=OuterRef('pk')).values('father__grandfather').annotate(
        sons_count=Count('id')).values('sons_count')

 data = GrandFather.objects.annotate(sons=Subquery(sons))
 
 print(son_count_of_all_grandfather.values_list('name', 'sons'))
```

example for here in data
<QuerySet [('grand father 1', 4), ('grand father 2', 1)]>